# Flutter Webrtc Build error on M1 android and ios

Tags: flutter, webrtc, flutter-dependencies, apple-m1

I am trying to build a webrtc flutter app on my m1 macbook air. But I got different issues both on android and ios. Latest one ^0.8.2 has error on both then  ^0.7.0+hotfix.1 demo [demo](https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/flutter-webrtc-demo) only works for android.

On iOS part 'Libyuv''s deployment target is set to 8.0 but min deployment target is 9.0 occurs. I set the deployment target above 10 then it still happens.

```
/Users/alperenbaskaya/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_webrtc-0.7.1/ios/Classes/FlutterWebRTCPlugin.h:8:9: fatal error: 'WebRTC/WebRTC.h' file not found
    #import <WebRTC/WebRTC.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
/Users/alperenbaskaya/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_webrtc-0.7.1/ios/Classes/FlutterRTCMediaStream.m:3:9: fatal error: 'WebRTC/WebRTC.h' file not found
    #import <WebRTC/WebRTC.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
In file included from /Users/alperenbaskaya/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_webrtc-0.7.1/ios/Classes/FlutterRTCFrameCapturer.m:8:
/Users/alperenbaskaya/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_webrtc-0.7.1/ios/Classes/FlutterRTCFrameCapturer.h:6:9: fatal error: 'WebRTC/WebRTC.h' file not found
    #import <WebRTC/WebRTC.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
In file included from /Users/alperenbaskaya/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_webrtc-0.7.1/ios/Classes/FlutterRTCDataChannel.m:2:
In file included from /Users/alperenbaskaya/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_webrtc-0.7.1/ios/Classes/FlutterRTCDataChannel.h:1:
/Users/alperenbaskaya/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_webrtc-0.7.1/ios/Classes/FlutterWebRTCPlugin.h:8:9: fatal error: 'WebRTC/WebRTC.h' file not found
    #import <WebRTC/WebRTC.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build description
    note: Build preparation complete
    /Users/alperenbaskaya/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter-webrtc-demo/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 4.3, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99. (in target 'Libyuv' from project 'Pods')
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 8 Plus.
```

After a workaround I updated libyuv deployment target but now I got following ios Error;

```
        objc[66512]: Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x20d426c10) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x113d3c2b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[66512]: Class AMSupportURLSession is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x20d426c60) and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x113d3c308). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    warning: [CP] Unable to find matching .xcframework slice in 'ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator ios-arm64_armv7' for the current build architectures (arm64 x86_64 i386).
In file included from /Users/alperenbaskaya/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_webrtc-0.8.2/ios/Classes/FlutterRTCPeerConnection.m:2:
/Users/alperenbaskaya/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_webrtc-0.8.2/ios/Classes/FlutterWebRTCPlugin.h:8:9: fatal error: 'WebRTC/WebRTC.h' file not found
    #import <WebRTC/WebRTC.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Analyzing workspace
    note: Constructing build description
    note: Build preparation complete
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 8 Plus.
```

On android side I got following;

```
Execution failed for task ':flutter_webrtc:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For version ^0.8.2 following solutions work for me.

***iOS***

in *ios/Podfile* add following to end of file.

```
    post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |build_configuration|
      build_configuration.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'arm64 i386'
    end
  end
end
```

Then clean your project and follow these steps as santoshakil mentioned [santoshakilsanswer](https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/flutter-webrtc/issues/713#issuecomment-983476313); (Those steps work for me if not follow all steps mentioned in link)

```
flutter clean && flutter pub get
cd ios
arch -x86_64 pod update
arch -x86_64 pod install
then at the top of your Pod file, paste this line platform :ios, '10.0'
right click on ios folder and open in xcode and then set all deployment target to 10
```

***Android***
Your android/app/build.gradle look like below as [webrtcflutterdemo](https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/flutter-webrtc-demo)

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.cloudwebrtc.flutterwebrtcdemo"
        minSdkVersion 21 
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

android/app/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.cloudwebrtc.flutterwebrtcdemo">

    <!-- The INTERNET permission is required for development. Specifically,
         flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:label="flutter_webrtc_demo"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <meta-data
```

***EDIT***
For Android side, i can not build for compilesdk and targetsdk 31. Temporary solution is downgrading compilesdk to 30. It is about jdk version on your mac device.